# How do I sanitize text input with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a textarea that receives input from the user and I am using `htmlspecialchars($_POST['bio']);` to sanitize the input.

Whenever I try to test the following input: `<script>alert('1');</script>`
It works as expected on my local dev machine but when I test it on a webhosting server I get the following error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

What I mean by sanitizing input is basically I want to disallow injected javascript code. So writing `<script>alert('1');</script` should display in plain text and not execute code to show an alert box. Instead of displaying in plain text, I get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is for putting special characters into HTML, so there is not a parse error with &, ', ", <, and >. What do you mean sanitize the input? If you're storing the data into a database, you need not worry about it if you use prepared statements. Your other issue is separate. Try setting your folder permission to 755 and your file permission to 644.

Comment: A 403 response has nothing to do with use of `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: By default the webhosting settings have those settings set. To test, I tried elevated permissions and set everything to 755.

Removing <script>alert('1')</script> and simply adding something basic like: hello world would work fine.